# What are the advantages/disadvantages of ways to use php template files?

Tags: php, templates, html

I saw people using php files template parts that are basically php files with no (or very little) logic, that only insert/echo the dynamic content in the respective places. Maybe using the ternary operator.

**Variant 1:**

```php
<div>
<h1>Hello <?php echo $username ?></h1>
</div>
```

But I also saw the approach of having a html/php file with no php at all in it, but having placeholders that will be replaced.

**Variant 2:**

*template file:*

```php
<div>
<h1>Hello PLACEHOLDER_USERNAME</h1>
</div>
```

*logic file:*

```php
$HTML = file_get_contents('template.php', true);

$HTML = str_replace(
    'PLACEHOLDER_USERNAME',
    $username,
    $HTML
);
echo $HTML;
```

I like that the template files are a little "*cleaner*" with the second variant. But for complex templates the replacing might become confusing. One also has to use a work-around like `ob_start()` when for example using `wp_editor()`:

```php
ob_start();
wp_editor( $content, 'content'); 
$editorHTML = ob_get_clean();

$HTML = str_replace('PLACEHOLDER_EDITOR', $editorHTML, $HTML);
```

**Is there a recommended way to handle this for WP development?

What are some advantages and disadvantages of either way (besides personal preference)?**

### Update

I guess one big difference would be if the content is needed to be returned by a function, like for *short code* insertion. But variant 1 in conjunction with the code below might be easier to maintain than lots of replacements.

```php
ob_start();
require('template.php');
return ob_get_clean();
```

Comment: For what its worth I've literally never seen variant 2 implemented anywhere. The lack of any strict syntax for variables makes it seem very fragile. Plus running `str_replace()` multiple times on large templates on every request is going to be very slow. I'd suggest either just using PHP variables and functions the normal way, or using an established template solution like [Timber](https://github.com/timber/timber) if that's not sufficient.

Comment: Variant 2 was taught to me in a WP tutorial, but it seemed weird to me to run str_replace multiple times on each template file

Comment: I'd be very wary of whatever that tutorial said.